# System of linear Partial Differential Equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

I am looking for a good reference on the generalization of characteristic curves to a system of linear partial differential equations.
Specifically my problem is of the following form: for $A,B$ real valued $n\times n$ matrices and $G\left( x,y\right):R^{2}\to R^{n}$ satisfy:
$$G_{x}-yAG_{y}=BG.$$
I appreciate any help or reference for a method to solve such linear pde.